# Cannot install php7.0-curl on Ubuntu 16.04 & PHP 7

Tags: 16.04, php7

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get -f install`.

Comment: not working same error message

Comment: Try @Videonauth's answer.

Comment: If that doesn't go, you could try a `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: same error not working

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg -r  php7-*` and then run `sudo apt-get install php php-common`.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either do:

```
sudo apt-get install php php-common
```

or

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

to solve this dependency issue, however, I would opt for the first one, the second is like solving fine details with a sledgehammer.

If this all really doesn't solve your problem, then you might as well check if you have the package repositories enabled

[image]
[image]
and run an:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

before retrying.

---

Following procedure retrieved from chat discussion:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.0/php7.0-common_7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1_i386.deb
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.0/php7.0-curl_7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i php7.0-common_7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i php7.0-curl_7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1_i386.deb
```

Solved it. Packages for the 'amd64' architecture can be found at [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com).

Comment: Good answer.  The advantage of the second one is that it will fix any other problems you have at the same time.

Comment: If I could +1 more than once...  :)  Except you keep stealing my thoughts right before I put them down :(

Comment: Hahaha, well I'm answering right now in between coding on a program, and as soon I get a thought I'll add it :) so simply coincidence

Comment: still same error not working.

Comment: Try downloading the package here http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.0/php7.0-curl_7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb and then install it by hand with `dpkg -i php7.0-curl_7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb` and let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: I am using 32-bit system

Comment: Then download it for the respective architecture here http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.0/php7.0-common_7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1_i386.deb and then `sudo dpkg -i php7.0-common_7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1_i386.deb`

Comment: above package installed but now this errot message appear:                               php7.0-curl : Depends: php7.0-common (= 7.0.4-7ubuntu2) but 7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1 is to be installed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42043/discussion-between-videonauth-and-habibun).